# Why is the bone group remove button disabled?

Tags: interface, armature, bones

I want to delete these bone groups but the remove button is disabled. How do I unlock and delete them?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must be in *pose mode*.

Select the armature and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>, or set the mode in *3D view > Header*:

[image]